# ClassNotFoundException when connecting to Oracle Database

Tags: java, database, oracle, classnotfoundexception

I've written a simple Program to test if the Oracle databse connection works. I'm not doing it in netbeans or eclipse, I'm just writing it in notepad++ and compilation,run by command prompt.
This is my program

```
import java.sql.*;

public class OracleCon{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL","SYSTEM","root");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from user_details");
            while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+rs.getInt(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));
            }
            con.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }   
}
```

The error is ClassNotfoundexception oracle.jdbc.driver.oracledriver when running the program.
I searched and found lot of suggestion in stackoverflow, even I set the class path in environment variables too. Still not working. So I've no other choice than creating this thread. I know solving these kind of problems will be very frustrating than solving errors in programs. I've worked with mysql previously, but this is my first time in Oracle database. My installed version is 12c.

Comment: Do you understand what the error means? Find or download the Oracle JDBC driver and make sure it is in the class path.

Comment: did you put the oracledriver in classpath?

Comment: Yeah I understood what that error means. let me show my CLASSPATH in environment variables..  G:\app\root\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar;.;

Answer (score 0):

Download odbc jar from fllowing website:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html

and add into your build path.

put this jar in your projects's lib folder.

then right click the jar and click 'Add to Build Path' option [referencing Eclipse as an IDE]

Hope this resolve your query.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem. thank for your reply guys. I mistyped the name as ojdbc.jar instead of ojdbc6.jar. Wasted more than 3 hours for my silly mistake. grrrr.. I would not have noticed it If I didnt copied it for pasting it here.